# Kind of blocks in Python

Tags: python, ruby, python-2.7

In Ruby I can say:

```
def get_connection
  db = connect_to_db()
  yield
  db.close()
end
```

and then call it

```
get_connection do
  # action1.....
  # action2.....
  # action3.....
end
```

In Python I have to say

```
def get_connection(code_block):
  db = connect_to_db()
  code_block()
  db.close()

get_connection(method1)

def method1():
   # action1.....
   # action2.....
   # action3.....
```

It's not convenient since I have to create an extra `method1`. Notice that `method1` can be big. Is there any way to emulate Ruby's anonymous blocks in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use the 'with' statement:

## Using classes

```
class get_connection(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.connect_to_db()
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.close()
    def some_db_method(self,...):
        ...
```

And use it like this:

```
with get_connection() as db:
    db.some_db_method(...)
```

This does the following:

```
 self.connect_to_db()
 db.some_db_method(...)
 self.close()
```

Have a look here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html . You can use the arguments taken by `__exit__` to handle exceptions within the `with` statement, etc.

## Using functions

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def db_connection():
    db = connect_to_db()
    yield db
    db.close()
```

and use this:

```
with db_connection() as db:
    db.some_db_method()
```

(Perhaps this is closer to your ruby equivalent. Also, see here for more details: http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)

Hope this helps

Comment: can I get rid of creating a class?

Comment: why don't use local methods?

Comment: or even lambdas if a method is short.

Comment: @AlanDert what do you mean by local methods? In python there are functions, class methods, and lambdas. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: I mean a method inside a method.

Comment: @AlanDert you can do that the way you did in your example; what's wrong with that, some extra `()` ?